# iPod touch tether to shared internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, ipod-touch

Does anyone know if it's possible to connect an iPod touch to a wireless network shared through your computer?  I know how to share the network connection but need to know whether the iPod find the network and connect to the internet.

The scenario is:

1. A laptop with a wired connection running Windows Vista
2. An iPod touch needing internet access
3. No option to purchase a wireless router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, I do this all the time at work.

Set up an ad-hoc network on Windows.

Choose the network on the iPod.

Simples!

Comment: FYI I managed to get hold on one to test and can verify that this works.  Thanks!